# Unwanted transparent space with skewed div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a site with skewed/rotated divs, but I've got a problem with the ones that have fixed background image.

The code describes the issue best:

https://codepen.io/poveu/pen/pWJwYx

```
<div class="skewed_fixed">
        <div class="content">
      This parent's background is fixed. When you scroll down, there's still that white body background above, and this text scrolls into it.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="skewed_normal">
    <div class="content">
      This background is not fixed and behaves properly.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="margin"></div>

.skewed_fixed {
    background: url(http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldador-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
}

.skewed_normal {
    background: url(http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldador-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.margin {
    height: 600px;
}
```

(background-size: cover and width: 100% is here just to make the bg fit 100% width; margin div is to make the page scrollable)

I want to scroll the whole div with its background "mask" so the white space disappears when scrolling down.

I've tried to mix it with transform-origin: left; but then the transparent space appears on the bottom of the div.

Is there any easy (non JS) way to achieve what I want?

Comment: why did you set `background-attachment: fixed` if you want to scroll it?

Comment: I don't want the background to scroll. I want it to stay in this position BUT without that white space. What's weird, background-position doesn't make it - there's still that blank space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used translate property with skew property. Try this.

```css
.skewed_fixed {
    background: url(http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldador-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transform: skewY(-3deg) translate(0px, -50px);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.skewed_normal {
    background: url(http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldador-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    transform: skewY(-3deg) translate(0px, -50px);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.margin {
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed_fixed">
  <div class="content">
      This parent's background is fixed. When you scroll down, there's still that white body background above, and this text scrolls into it.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="skewed_normal">
    <div class="content">
      This background is not fixed and behaves properly.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="margin"></div>
```

Comment: Well, actually, this workaround works only because ratio of the dog image fits the screen ratio. The issue still exists when you resize your window with Chrome debugger. I think this is some kind of bug, because Firefox displays everything properly. I'm going to have to give up on fixed background, I will make a little paralax effect with javascript instead.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, because this workaround does its job in almost every similar case.

Answer (score 0):

You could play on positions and margin or padding to compensate the empty space :

```
 .skewed_fixed {
    background: url(http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldador-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: 0px -100px;
    top:-50px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but even your code doesn't work properly - it scrolls properly for various pixels, but look what happens when you scroll a little bit lower - the blank space suddenly pops out again. Weird! https://codepen.io/poveu/pen/rGVpza And of course top negative margin makes the empty space appear on the bottom of this div

Comment: See ! Here is an explanation for the "empty" space appearence :

Comment: This empty space is in fact the background color of your .skewed_fixed div (try a background-color:yellow; and you'll see what I mean). In fact, when you scroll down, your background image is staying fixed,  and so the background color of the div appears. To prevent the background to be seen, you could zoom in your background-image (background-size:110%) and decrease your background minus position (background-position:0px -300px)...

Comment: I even tried with your second Idea, BUT 
check the second code and see what happens when you scroll lower to the second div - the white space suddenly appears at some point of scrolling https://codepen.io/poveu/pen/rGVpza

Comment: what if you increase the background-position minus top ? No more withe space on my test with : background-position: 0px -550px; ... If you are able to get a bigger background, that will definitely solve your trouble

Comment: I don't think you understand me, I'm not good at explaining :P BG position has nothing to do with this sudden pop out. You can even set background-size to 300% and background-position to 0px -700px and still you will see that white spice when you scroll lower. Just try it yourself on the second codepen I posted. Slowly scroll to the very bottom of page while watching that first div and you'll notice what I mean. It looks like some kind of bug. OH I JUST FOUND OUT this bug doesn't seem to be present on Firefox! Probably you're using Firefox and didn't get my point! Try it on Chrome or Opera.